# mysql single quotation symbol ' or `

Tags: mysql, syntax

Would someone explain what's the difference between  ' and `  in mysql, aren't they both single quotation? For some reason, in some situation, ' doesn't work while ` does. When to use which?

Comment: ` is used for identifiers, ' for literal strings. Take a look at the manual mentioned above: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html ^^

Answer (score 3):

String quoted with back ticks (`) is interpreted by MySQL as an identifier.

Single quotes (“'”) are used for enclosing String literals.